# JavaEE: Ensure WAR files may not be changed

Tags: security, jakarta-ee

I am currently working in a WEB Java project and I have the following requirement: I have to make sure our customers don't have access to the packaged files in order to change them. Actually, I'd like to do that with only a few of those classes but without using any obfuscators due to the size of my project and the resources it uses to accomplish some tasks (reflection, annotations, interceptors, etc).
Does anybody have any tips?

Thanks,
Luan

Comment: Obfuscators or else, this is impossible unfortunately. (Imagine if it was possible, pirated software would not be a thing. :) )

Comment: @GaborLengyel thanks for your answer. I think it would be a bit difficult to use an obfuscator here because of some drawbacks as I said. Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. What you want to achieve is not possible in any way. Obfuscation would not help very much even if you could use it. I think your problem can best be solved in legal contracts.

Comment: It might be the best way. Thanks for your support.